# How to set up email form with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, email, contact-form, mailto

I am trying to create a simple email form with php but after stylizing it and everything, it does not work. I want to fix the form I already have, not use an ugly template written by someone else. How can I set this up so the admin email receives notifications of the content filled in the name, email, and message fields. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is the html:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php">
  <p class="contact-name">
  <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="contact-email">
<input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
  </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message"     name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="mailto:email@example.com">Send Your Email</a>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
        </form>
```

and here is php:

```
$admin_email = 'email@example.com';

class Contact_Form{
function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->subject = 'Contact from'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
    $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
}
```

validation code and then...

```
    private function sendEmail(){
    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
         "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
    }
}


function sendRequest(){
    $this->validateFields();
    if($this->response_status)
    {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
    $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: haven't tested your code, but seems ok, normally when emails don't work for people is because they don't have a smtp server installed on their computer and are trying to test it locally, and / or don't have the proper port (I think it was port 25) opened on the router / firewall. A good way to try your code out would be to test it on an production environment ( an actual hosting if you have one )

Comment: Yeah, that code looks alright. Enable error reporting with: `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` - and see if it fires any errors. If not, then @aleation is right.

Comment: @rm-vanda the problem is that with the mail() function normally it just return true or false, it will return true if `mail()` function is triggered with no errors, but that doesn't guarantee it to be sent. It's just been sent to "the server" and now it's its problem xD

Comment: Please never post mail addresses on the internet. Someone might really own the address and thanks to you will now be raped by spammers. Use `example.com` or `example.org` for such purposes; this is the sanctioned URL for examples.